# Regex for not only spaces

Tags: regex, forms, input

I am looking for regex that not allowing only spaces (but more than one). One allows (blank space).
I got something like this `.*\S.*'` or this `.*[^ ].*` but i want to allow only one space but not more than one only spaces.

Comment: Could you supply match and unmatch examples?

Comment: Probably `pattern="\S*(?:\s\S*)?"` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
pattern="\S*(?:\s\S*)?"
```

The pattern will get parsed as a `^(?:\S*(?:\s\S*)?)$` pattern and will match

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\S*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace
  - `(?:\s\S*)?` - an optional sequence of a whitespace and zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `)` - end of a non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.